# Akka Http server failing with SQLTransientConnectionException when run in Intellij Idea

Tags: postgresql, scala, intellij-idea, slick, akka-http

I have an Akka-Http project where I am trying to run the server from Intellij Idea. The project runs perfectly fine when I run it using the command line

```
sbt -mem 2048 "project projectName" run
```

However, when I try to run the server from Intellij [image]

I get the following error

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61427:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/hive/server/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/common/queue/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/common/event/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.stripe/stripe-java/jars/stripe-java-10.14.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/software.amazon.ion/ion-java/bundles/ion-java-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.18.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5/jars/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.1.13.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-core/jars/flying-saucer-core-9.1.13.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/webjars-locator-core/jars/webjars-locator-core-0.35.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.webjars/swagger-ui/jars/swagger-ui-2.2.6.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/macro-compat_2.12/jars/macro-compat_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/machinist_2.12/jars/machinist_2.12-0.6.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-macros_2.12/jars/cats-macros_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-kernel_2.12/jars/cats-kernel_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-core_2.12/jars/cats-core_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/jawn-parser_2.12/jars/jawn-parser_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/imp_2.12/jars/imp_2.12-0.3.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scommons.service/scommons-service-dao_2.12/jars/scommons-service-dao_2.12-0.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scalaz/scalaz-core_2.12/bundles/scalaz-core_2.12-7.2.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra.scalate/scalate-util_2.12/jars/scalate-util_2.12-1.8.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatra.scalate/scalate-core_2.12/jars/scalate-core_2.12-1.8.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.12/bundles/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-java8-compat_2.12/bundles/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.8.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.12.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.reflections/reflections/jars/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/jars/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.postgresql/postgresql/bundles/postgresql-42.2.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-2.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/jars/flyway-core-4.2.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/jars/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.57.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.15-beta2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/jars/log4j-to-slf4j-2.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.4.9.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.5.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/jars/commons-compress-1.9.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.jtidy/jtidy/jars/jtidy-r938.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.9.9.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/jars/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/jars/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/javax.validation/validation-api/jars/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-models/bundles/swagger-models-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-jaxrs/bundles/swagger-jaxrs-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-core/jars/swagger-core-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.swagger/swagger-annotations/bundles/swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.sentry/sentry-logback/jars/sentry-logback-1.7.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.sentry/sentry/jars/sentry-1.7.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.github.nremond/pbkdf2-scala_2.12/jars/pbkdf2-scala_2.12-0.6.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-parser_2.12/jars/circe-parser_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-optics_2.12/jars/circe-optics_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-numbers_2.12/jars/circe-numbers_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-jawn_2.12/jars/circe-jawn_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-java8_2.12/jars/circe-java8_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-generic_2.12/jars/circe-generic_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-generic-extras_2.12/jars/circe-generic-extras_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-core_2.12/jars/circe-core_2.12-0.9.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/de.heikoseeberger/akka-http-circe_2.12/jars/akka-http-circe_2.12-1.21.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/bundles/HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.12/bundles/slick_2.12-3.2.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick-hikaricp_2.12/bundles/slick-hikaricp_2.12-3.2.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.12/jars/play-json_2.12-2.6.12.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-functional_2.12/jars/play-functional_2.12-2.6.12.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.12/jars/akka-stream_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.12/jars/akka-slf4j_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.12/jars/akka-protobuf_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-parsing_2.12/jars/akka-parsing_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.12/jars/akka-http_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-xml_2.12/jars/akka-http-xml_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http-core_2.12/jars/akka-http-core_2.12-10.1.7.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.12/jars/akka-actor_2.12-2.5.19.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.12/bundles/ssl-config-core_2.12-0.3.6.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/bundles/paranamer-2.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/jars/javax.mail-1.6.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-json-common_2.12/jars/jwt-json-common_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-core_2.12/jars/jwt-core_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-core-impl_2.12/jars/jwt-core-impl_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.pauldijou/jwt-circe_2.12/jars/jwt-circe_2.12-0.16.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.osinka.i18n/scala-i18n_2.12/jars/scala-i18n_2.12-1.0.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv_2.12/jars/kantan.csv_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv-generic_2.12/jars/kantan.csv-generic_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.csv-cats_2.12/jars/kantan.csv-cats_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs-shapeless_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs-shapeless_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.nrinaudo/kantan.codecs-cats_2.12/jars/kantan.codecs-cats_2.12-0.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung/lutung/jars/lutung-0.0.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-sqs_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-sqs_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-kinesis_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-kinesis_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.lightbend.akka/akka-stream-alpakka-csv_2.12/jars/akka-stream-alpakka-csv_2.12-0.20.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/jars/itextpdf-5.5.11.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.iheart/ficus_2.12/jars/ficus_2.12-1.4.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client/jars/google-oauth-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/jars/google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.http-client/google-http-client/jars/google-http-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-20.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.apis/google-api-services-safebrowsing/jars/google-api-services-safebrowsing-v4-rev44-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.google.api-client/google-api-client/jars/google-api-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.virtuald/curvesapi/jars/curvesapi-1.04.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_core_2.12/jars/slick-pg_core_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_circe-json_2.12/jars/slick-pg_circe-json_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.tminglei/slick-pg_2.12/jars/slick-pg_2.12-0.16.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http_2.12/jars/swagger-akka-http_2.12-0.14.1.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala_2.12/jars/awscala_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-sts_2.12/jars/awscala-sts_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-stepfunctions_2.12/jars/awscala-stepfunctions_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-sqs_2.12/jars/awscala-sqs_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-simpledb_2.12/jars/awscala-simpledb_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-s3_2.12/jars/awscala-s3_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-redshift_2.12/jars/awscala-redshift_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-iam_2.12/jars/awscala-iam_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-emr_2.12/jars/awscala-emr_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-ec2_2.12/jars/awscala-ec2_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-dynamodb_2.12/jars/awscala-dynamodb_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.seratch/awscala-core_2.12/jars/awscala-core_2.12-0.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.github.julien-truffaut/monocle-core_2.12/jars/monocle-core_2.12-1.4.0.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator/bundles/java-uuid-generator-3.1.5.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.12/bundles/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-paranamer/bundles/jackson-module-paranamer-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/bundles/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.11.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/bundles/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.8.11.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/bundles/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.6.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/bundles/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.9.8.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.12/bundles/shapeless_2.12-2.3.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/jmespath-java/jars/jmespath-java-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/jars/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions/jars/aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sqs/jars/aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns/jars/aws-java-sdk-sns-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-simpledb/jars/aws-java-sdk-simpledb-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-redshift/jars/aws-java-sdk-redshift-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kms/jars/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-kinesis/jars/aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-iam/jars/aws-java-sdk-iam-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-emr/jars/aws-java-sdk-emr-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/jars/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/jars/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.285.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.342.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/user1/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/scoring/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/payments/data/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/tenants/data/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/monitor/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/mailer/mandrill-api/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/mailer/flows/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/mailer/templates/.jvm/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/hive/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/hive/dao/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/hive/api/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/edr/events/target/scala-2.12/classes:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/project_root/common/test/target/scala-2.12/classes projectName.Main
2019-08-19 21:07:23,389 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger  - Slf4jLogger started
2019-08-19 21:07:23,686 INFO  projectName.Main$  - Kinesis Event writer disabled
2019-08-19 21:07:24,488 INFO  projectName.data.PostgresDriver  -  >>> binding uuid -> java.util.UUID 
2019-08-19 21:07:24,489 INFO  projectName.data.PostgresDriver  -  >>> binding text -> java.lang.String 
2019-08-19 21:07:24,489 INFO  projectName.data.PostgresDriver  -  >>> binding bool -> Boolean 
2019-08-19 21:07:24,505 INFO  projectName.data.PostgresDriver  -  >>> binding json -> io.circe.Json 
2019-08-19 21:07:24,505 INFO  projectName.data.PostgresDriver  -  >>> binding jsonb -> io.circe.Json 
2019-08-19 21:07:24,527 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource  - database - Started.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at projectName.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: database - Connection is not available, request timed out after 20003ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
    at slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:453)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
    at projectName.data.DatabaseService.<init>(DatabaseService.scala:16)
    at projectName.data.DatabaseService$.default(DatabaseService.scala:23)
    at projectName.data.DefaultDatabaseServiceProvider.$init$(DatabaseService.scala:30)
    at projectName.Main$.<init>(Main.scala:25)
    at projectName.Main$.<clinit>(Main.scala)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:263)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:94)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:79)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:193)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:430)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:64)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:570)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:563)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:514)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:201)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:57)
        at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:364)
        ... 1 more
```

I am unable to find the root cause of this issue. My application.conf file looks something like this

```
database {
  host = "localhost"
  port = 5432
  username = ""
  password = ""
  db_name = ""
  dataSourceClass = org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  numThreads = 5
  maxConnections = 5
  connectionTimeout = "20s"
}
```

My dependency versions are as follows

```
  private val slickVersion = "3.2.1"
  private val slickHikaricpVersion = "3.2.3"
  private val slickPgVersion = "0.16.3"
```

The most surprising part is that if it was a jdbc issue I would not have been able to run the project using command line, but it runs like a charm using the sbt command via command line. Any pointers to this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your conf file is not included in the build. Is the folder with the conf file marked as `resources` in your project structure? Try printing out some of the config variables on startup, before the DB connection is formed, and make sure they exist.